# Render return html into text

Tags: python, django

This is urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.login_page, name='login_page'),
]
```

my views.py like this

```
def login_page(request):
    return render(request, 'mileage/login_page.html', {})
```

this is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width" >
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#4599e8">
<div class="title"><span><h1>Test</h1></span></div>
<div class="home_password">
    <div class="password"><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></div>
    <div class="button"><button>OK</button></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And start server, but my localhost:8080/ shows only html text not page.

Using Chrome Developer Console, I checked element.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
"
   my html code here.
"
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Have you restarted the server?

Comment: @Sayse sure....

Answer (score 0):

Who is inserting all your html code inside the pre tag is your browser because it probably receives a `Content-type: text/plain` header with the response and it thinks you want to see the html code instead of the rendered webpage.

Try making a test using:

```
render(request, 'mileage/login_page.html', {}, content_type='text/html')
```

If it works, set the DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE constant to 'text/html' in your settings.

> DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE
>
> Default: 'text/html'
>
> Default content type to use for all HttpResponse objects, if a MIME
>   type isn’t manually specified. Used with DEFAULT_CHARSET to construct
>   the Content-Type header.

Probably an environment variable is messing you up with this, It's weird that it has a default 'text/plain' content type set.